# How to auto-decode JWT via Istio for backend service?

Tags: kubernetes, jwt, decode, istio

I am using k8s and istio to manage my mesh network.

I have already used istio to validate JWT but I want more option about decoding the JWT(only payload) inside my backend service.

I think it's a good solution to add more headers into the request.
Every services doesn't have to validate JWT, doesn't need to decode the payload but just has to use headers.

Any ideas how this works ?

Answer (score 0):

Envoy Lua filter can do this for you: https://github.com/BarDweller/istio-content-based-routing/blob/master/istio-envoy-filter-jwt-lua.yaml

Detailed discussion is in https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/8444, but they had another more complicated use case.